# Civicrm 4..6.10-drupal is missing directory CRM/common

Tags: installation

Upgraded from 4.1.15 to 4.6.10 with no errors, setup file system ownership & permissions, cleared template_c cache, ran drush cvapi system.flush
Working but layouts are wrong and the log file contains errors with
"User warning: Smarty error: unable to read resource                                     : &quot;CRM/common/action.tpl&quot; in trigger_error() (line 1094 of ../sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/Smarty/Smarty.class.php).

Directory modules/civicrm/CRM does not contain a common directory.

Answer (score 2):

Ive resolved my issue by drilling into the fine Civicrm template documentation. The log file leaves out the initial part of the directory so whats being referenced is actually sites/all/modules/civicrm/templates/CRM/common which does exist in 4.6.10. Whats missing is the file action.tpl, it was present in Ver 4.1.

Root cause though was having an old custom tpl file in sites/all/civicrm_templates/CRM/common which called action.tpl.

Fixed by deleting the old custom tpl files, then working through the version control checking the issue documentation to see if custom tpl files are still needed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have also get the same issue today after upgrading the civicrm. Common folder is missing from all 4.6.10 version.